# PHP: Cannot print first value of DOMDocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I have a PHP script that is supposed to read an HTML file and then return the contents of the first `<h1>` tag that it finds. I do not want to use regex or the Simple HTML DOM Parser please - just plain, easy PHP.

This is my code thus far:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTMLFile($post_url);
$matches = $document->getElementsByTagName('h1');
$first_h1 = $matches->item(0);
echo $first_h1;
```

However, when I run the code, I get an error that says `PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string`

Can anyone help me with where I am going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

SOLUTION: Replacing the last line with `echo $first_h1->nodeValue;` seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `$first_h1` is a `DOMElement` object rather than a string, and it has no method to convert itself to a string, so you cannot simply echo it out. You can, however do a `var_dump` on it:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTMLFile($post_url);
$matches = $document->getElementsByTagName('h1');
$first_h1 = $matches->item(0);
var_dump($first_h1);
```

If you need to get the text contents of the element (i.e. the text between the tags), use the nodeValue property:

```
echo $first_h1->nodeValue;
```

Comment: That, unfortunately, does not leave me with the contents between the first <h1> tag. Do you know of a way to parse the var_dump output so that only the string contents are returned? I am a complete PHP beginner.

Comment: Just added that to my answer.

Comment: Using echo $first_h1->textContent; seems to work 100%! Thanks for the help!

Comment: There are differences between nodeValue and textContent, so you will probably want to read up in the PHP manual on those two properties.

Comment: Noted. Looks like nodeValue is the better choice here.

Answer (score 0):

**$document** is an object which can not be converted to string (some objects can).

See this **[link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php)** for all properties and methods it has to offer, e.g.

```
echo $document->tagName;
```

or

```
echo $document->textContent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the entire tag value with C14N method of the DOMNode class:

```
echo $first_h1->C14N();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.c14n.php